# Borel algebra is generated by the collection of all half-open intervals

Tags: measure-theory

This question is based on the following from *Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure* by Bartle. We are given the following example and exercise:

> Let X be the set ${\mathbf R}$ of real numbers. The **Borel algebra** is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all open intervals $(a,b)$ in ${\mathbf R}$. Observe that the Borel algebra ${\mathbf B}$ is also the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all closed intervals $[a,b]$ in ${\mathbf R}$
>
> Exercise 2.B. Show that the Borel algebra ${\mathbf B}$ is also generated by the collection of all half-open intervals $(a,b]=\{x\in {\mathbf R}: a<x\leqslant b\}$

The definition of sigma algebras we are given is that they are unions and complements of a family of sets on a universal set $X$.

My thought on the way to solve this was to use something like
$$
(a,b)=\cup_{n=1}^\infty[a+1/n,b-1/n]
$$
and similarly
$$
(a,b)=\cup_{n=1}^\infty(a,b-1/n]
$$
to show that we can construct $(a,b)$ as a union of either the closed or the half-open intervals.

What I'm wondering about is, first I would like to check that the above is a correct answer of course, and also I wonder whether I've missed some other trick which doesn't involve these constructions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you have the right idea. But the solution you gave is not complete.

Let $\mathfrak{B}$ be the Borel set generated by intervals of the form $[a,b]$ and  $\mathfrak{B}^*$ be the Borel set generated by elements of the form $(a,b)$

By the relation you gave,

$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [a+1/n,b-1/n]$$

You showed that any open interval $(a,b)$ can be written as a countable union of closed sets.

Hence, $(a,b)\in \mathfrak{B}$

Now since each element of $\mathfrak{B}^*$ is a countable union, intersection and complement of open intervals. Thus you have

$$\mathfrak{B}^*\subseteq\mathfrak{B}$$

Now, **you also need to show $\mathfrak{B}\subseteq\mathfrak{B}^*$.**

I'm sure, since you have the right idea, that you'll be able to show that too.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. I was hoping there was some kind of clever trick without all these constructions.

Comment: "Now since each element of  is a countable union, intersection and complement of open intervals. " Why would any Borel set in $B^*$ be of that form?

Comment: @Aman: Let $x\in\mathfrak{B}^*$ then $x$ is a countable union, intersection and complement. Wherever, there is an open interval in the expansion of $x$ you can replace it by the above expression and thus you have. $x\in\mathfrak{B}$

Comment: The point I wanted to make was that not every borel set is a countable union, intersection, complement of open sets, even though borel sigma algebra is generated by open sets. It is just the smallest sigma algebra containing open sets.

Comment: Ok. So just showing the containment of an open interval suffices?

Answer (score 5):

You showed that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the closed (resp. half-open) intervals *is a superset of* the Borel algebra. The other inclusion is still missing: Obtain $[a,b]$ using nothing but countable unions and complements of open intervals. A straight-forward possiblity is
$$[a,b]=\mathbb R\setminus\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left(\mathbb R\setminus(a-1/n,b+1/n)\right)\right)\text.$$

Reusing this representation, we obtain
$$(a,b]=(a,(a+b)/2)\cup[(a+b)/2,b]$$
for half-open intervals.

Comment: $$[a,b]=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (a-1/n,b+1/n)\text{ would be a cleaner version}$$ :)

Comment: Thank you; I edited the answer.

Comment: Swapnil Tripathi  Then w ecan  conclude that Borel algebra is generated by the closed intervals that you mensioned? how can it be proved formally?