On predictability of deterministic processes and approximation of Borel functions by left-continuous processes.
Let $(\Omega, (\mathcal F_t)_{t\geq 0}, \mathcal F)$ be a filtered measurable space. Consider the deterministic process $X(t,\omega) = h(t)$ where $h: \mathbb R_+ \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a function. Prove that $X$ (or just $h$) is a predictable process if and only if $h$ is Borel measurable.
In this link, @saz gave an answer using a result that says every Borel (measurable) function $h$ can be approximated by simple left continuous processes of the form
$$ s(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i 1_{(a_i,b_i]}(t), \quad n\geq1,\quad (a_i,b_i]'s \ \text{are disjoint}. $$
However, it seems that this is wrong. If this is true, it means that $1_A(t)$, where $A$ is a Borel set, can also be approximated by these simple, left-continuous functions. But I cannot prove or disprove this. Any help is appreciated.
Also, I don't know how to start the part where $h$ is first assumed to be predictable then it implies $h$ is Borel measurable. Thank you for all your help!
$$ $$

Why do you think this is wrong? Do you not know that any measurable function can be approximated by simple functions? Your first question is more on general measurable function rather than stochastic processes.

@Keen-ameteur Do you have a proof? Please read carefully since these are not usual simple functions, but a subclass of simple functions. See this answer

@JeffreyJao Every Borel set on $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a limit of half-open intervals, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043083/borel-algebra-is-generated-by-the-collection-of-all-half-open-intervals

@RozaTh You are making a mistake, those are Borel sets, which is the sigma algebra generated by many sub-families of sets, it's irrelevant here. Here, this is pointwise approximation of the indicator function, not the Borel sets. In the link you cite, there's no pointwise approximation. You should be careful (and the person who upvoted your comment as well) :)

The link to John Dawkins' answer doesn't work anymore so check this link

The predictable $\sigma$-algebra contains the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all deterministic continuous processes. In other words, the predictable $\sigma$-algebra contains $ \sigma(\Omega \times f^{-1}(A): A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R), f \ \text{is continuous})$. But this is just $\sigma \Big( \Omega \times \sigma_{\mathbb R}\left(f^{-1}(A):A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R), f \ \text{is continuous} \right) \Big)$ by a well-known lemma.
The $\sigma$-algebra generated by continuous functions  in topological spaces is called Baire $\sigma$-algebra, which coincides with Borel $\sigma$-algebra in metric spaces. This is given in Theorem 7.1.1, Real Analysis and Probability by R. Dudley. Thus,
$$ \sigma \Big( \Omega \times \sigma_{\mathbb R}\left(f^{-1}(A):A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R), f \ \text{is continuous} \right) \Big) = \sigma \Big( \Omega \times  \mathcal B(\mathbb R) \Big) =\sigma \Big( \Omega \times A :A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R) \Big).$$
If $h$ is Borel, then the map $(t,\omega)\mapsto X(t,\omega) = h(t)$ is predictable since $X^{-1}(A) = h^{-1}(A)\times \Omega$ is a predictable set because $h^{-1}(A)$ is Borel.
Now if $h$ is predictable, that means $h^{-1}(A)\times \Omega$ is a predictable set, in particular, it belongs to the product measure $  \mathcal B(\mathbb R) \otimes \mathcal F$, this implies $h^{-1}(A)$ is a Borel set. Indeed, set $H= h^{-1}(A)$ and fix one $\omega \in \Omega$, define $g: (\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)) \rightarrow (\Omega \times \mathbb R, \mathcal F \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ by $g(x) = (x,\omega)$, then g is measurable (check this) and hence $g^{-1}(H\times \Omega) = H \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$.
For your question on pointwise approximation, indeed it is true that not every Borel measurable function can be approximated pointwise by left-continuous functions. Such functions having that property must be in Baire class 2 because left-continuous functions can be approximated pointwise by continuous functions (Baire class 0) and thus belong to Baire class 1. Also, Lebesgue proved that every Baire class $\alpha$ is not empty and there are functions is this class that are not in previous classes 1,2,...,$\alpha-1$. And so there are functions in Baire class 3 that cannot be approximated by left-continuous functions. And remember that in $\mathbb R$ all Baire functions are just Borel functions as mentioned above.
